# What does "set -eu" do in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have googled and could not find an explanation of this combination.

What does `set -eu` do in the start of a bash shell script?

(I could find some explanations for `-e` but not `-eu`.)

Comment: Look up the bash set command and the switches -e and -u one at a time.

Comment: Would the question be answered when saying option `-eu`is the same as option `-e`and option `-u`? Also I think you should have tried a bit harder to answer it before asking this question.

Comment: @user253751 there's also `+eu` to revert `-eu`, things get messy :D

Comment: @U.Windl Searched for `-u` . Could not find anything. Therefore I asked

Comment: These are SHELL OPTIONS, toggled by using "set" or "shopt". #teachamantosearch :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the [bash man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/bash.1.html) under the section for [shell builtin commands](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20builtin%20commands) the `set` command is explained. `-e` and `-u` can be set separately, but are often combined when debugging along with `-x` to `set -eux` or in the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -eux`

```
-e      Exit  immediately  if  a  pipeline  (which  may  consist of a single simple
        command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL  GRAMMAR  above),  exits
        with  a non-zero status.  The shell does not exit if the command that fails
        is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword,
        part  of  the  test  following  the  if or elif reserved words, part of any
        command executed in a && or || list except the command following the  final
        &&  or  ||,  any  command  in  a pipeline but the last, or if the command's
        return value is being inverted with !.  If a compound command other than  a
        subshell  returns  a  non-zero status because a command failed while -e was
        being ignored, the shell does not exit.  A trap on ERR, if set, is executed
        before  the  shell exits.  This option applies to the shell environment and
        each subshell environment separately  (see  COMMAND  EXECUTION  ENVIRONMENT
        above),  and  may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands
        in the subshell.
```

```
-u      Treat  unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters "@"
        and "*" as an error when performing parameter expansion.  If  expansion  is
        attempted  on  an  unset  variable  or parameter, the shell prints an error
        message, and, if not interactive, exits with a non-zero status.
```

Comment: To add to the excellent answer, you would see this in scripts to improve error handling. Without `-e` the script will continue its execution when an underlying command returned an error code. In many cases, you'd want to terminate the script at that point. `-u` protects against accidental usage of a variable that is not defined, for example, if the script uses a variable `$foo`, but its value wasn't set before, the `-u` flag will tell bash to stop execution with an error.

Comment: @oleksii Thanks for your excellent addition!.

Comment: [set -x](https://itslinuxfoss.com/set-x-bash-script/#2) for debugging